# Custom attribute in DevExpress XAF

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I'm new here, I'm using DevExpress XAF for creating my win and web app within the XAF platform, but could not find clear answer for using `CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE` in XAF.

Let say I have database already in SQL server. When I add ORM Data Modeling Wizard to build Classes, I have Image fields (varbinary(max)) and i see CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE in properties, I would like to use it.

[Edit Attribute Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SybbO.jpg)

When the application is running the end user can Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, Load, Save

For getting  this i used CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE: `DevExpress.Persistent.Base.ImageEditor`

But i would like to end user able to TAKE A PICTURE FROM THEIR CAMERA  also for getting this CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE.

Answer (score 0):

*You* need to provide the code to implement your user functionality. The DevExpress XAF framework does not do everything for you.

The XAF approach for this would normally be to create a `ViewController` with a `SimpleAction`. There's [a tutorial for this](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112737/getting-started/comprehensive-tutorial/extend-functionality/add-a-simple-action). Then you need to write the code to interface with the camera (DevExpress does not provide any code for this). You can assign the captured image to your property editor with something like this:

```
((MyBusinessObject)View.CurrentObject).MyImageProperty = theImage;
```

It looks from your screenshot like you are building a Windows Forms XAF application but the approach would be similar for the web and mobile platforms.

The [Data Model Wizard](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/14810/devexpress-orm-tool/design-time-features/data-model-wizard) helps you create the C# classes that represent your data model and map it to the underlying SQL tables. It does not provide any ability to define functionality beyond this mapping.

When you assign the `ImageEditor` to a property, all you are doing is informing the framework that the data stored in the `varbinary` column is an image and XAF automatically assigns an appropriate property editor for this (which provides load, save, etc.)

Comment: would you please review my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/71002470/4885037